# Django admin page not showing user models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

My admin page is working fine except when logged in it is not showing any user models. It is hindering my work as I cannot manage users.
I have made custom models as shown below.
Database is MySQL.

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_restaurant = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    food_pref = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='veg')


class Restaurant(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    restaurant_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regisrar your models in`admin.py` file.

```
from . models import Model_Name
```

Then you can register your models in two ways:
I) `admin.site.register(Model_Name)`
II)

```
@admin.register(Model_Name)
Class Xyz(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Second method gives you more flexibility like `list_display, list_filter, date_hierarchy, etc.` for customising your Admin section/site.

You can look more about customising admin site at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#module-django.contrib.admin

Answer (score 3):

Have You registered them in admin.py?

```
from .models import ModelName

admin.site.register(ModelName)
```